# how to query restful rails app with curl?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, http, curl, rest

here's my problem..
resource: user
method: create

I call curl like this:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: text/xml' -d '<xml><login>john</login><password>123456</password></xml>' http://0.0.0.0:3000/users
```

but the params hash in rails look like this:

```
{"xml"=> {"login"=>"luca", "password"=>"123456"}}
```

I want it to look like this:

```
{"login"=>"luca", "password"=>"123456"}
```

I can get it to be like that if I pass the parameters on the url (...?login=luca&pas....), but that's not good...

any idea?

Comment: Does replacing 'xml' with 'user' in your XML string help?

Comment: nope.. I tried all possible variants.. xml user users request params parameters post .. I don't think that's the way to go..

Answer (score 3):

```
curl -X POST -d 'login=john&password=123456' http://0.0.0.0:3000/users
```

See also: [Stack Overflow: How do I make a POST request with curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84619/how-do-i-make-a-post-request-with-curl)

Comment: OK so the point is if I want true xml I must have a single root and readapt my controllers, else I can pass vars with the var=value&... syntax.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: text/xml' -d '<login>john</login><password>123456</password>' http://0.0.0.0:3000/users
```

What does that get you?

After getting your comment, why not access it through params[:xml] in your controller, rather than params[:login] and params[:password]?

```
@user = User.authenticate(params[:xml])
```

That will pass login and password to your model.

Comment: you can't add 2 nodes.. you'll get:
"attempted adding second root element to document"

Comment: yes, that is how I'm now circumventing the problem, but I was hoping to better understand why it doesn't work..

Comment: It doesn't work because '<login>john</login><password>123456</password>' is not a well formed XML document. The root node ends at </login>.

For root nodes and Immortals, "there can be only one." :)

Answer (score 1):

Hey I had this problem for a long time as well. I found out that you can do this -

Make a new defaults.rb inside the initializers directory: yourapp/config/initializers/defaults.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Base.include_root_in_json = false
```

Now the root should be gone from your json.